# Find number of triangles with integral sides and side lengths ≤ 2n

Tags: geometry, combinations, recursion

Find number of triangles with integral sides and side lengths less than or equal to $2n$.
I approached this method by recursion.

Say $A_{2n}\ $is the number of triangles with integral sides and side lengths less than or equal to $2n$.
$A_{2n-1}\ $ is the number of triangles with integral sides and side lengths less than or equal to $2n-1$ .

So $A_{2n}=A_{2n-1}+\left( \text{number of triangles having at least one side equal to} 2n \right) .$

How to count the number of triangles having at least one side equal to $2n$?

Also, is there any other better method to this other than generalization as well?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to count up instead of counting down...

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please use MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of triangles having at least one side equal to $2n$ is the number of couple $(a,b)$ with $a\ge b$ and $a+b > 2n$. That is, 
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum^{2n}_{b=1}\sum^{2n}_{a = \max(b,2n + 1-b)} 1 &= \sum^{2n}_{b=1} (2n+1 - \max(b,2n+1-b))\\
&=\sum^{2n}_{b=n+1} ((2n+1) - b) + \sum^{n}_{b=1} (2n+1 - (2n+1-b))\\
&=\sum^{1}_{c=n}c + \sum^{n}_{b=1} b\hspace{5em}(\text{where } c = 2n+1-b)\\
&= n(n+1)
\end{aligned}$$
In order to argue recursively, you would need to compute $A_{2n-1}$ in similar fashion as well.